# Post-processing screen image before rendering it on display

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, post-processing, imagefilter

I'm working on a tinny software (C# and WPF) that does some filtering to the screen output. Examples on the filtering I'm talking about:

- Customizable blue light filtering.
- Increase/Decrease screen brightness (via changing the colors, not actual brightness)
- Inverting screen colors.

And some more, but the simple idea is to tweak the pixel values of the screen after everything else is done rendering, but before showing the result.

**Q1: How can I actually access (and then edit) the screen image/frame?**

I've heard of getting and editing the screen DC directly (Win32) but I don't know if it's a good way, nor how to do it exactly.

**Q2: what is the best way of applying these filters?**

I think that tweaking every single pixel individually is a really bad way of doing it. (My code runs on the CPU and this process needs to be done every frame!)

**Q3: Is there an event or hook for when windows is refreshing/updating the screen?**

If yes, how can I register this process to it?

*Note: I want a really performant way so that I don't lose any frame rate if possible.*

*Note: My preferred language for this is C#, C++ is ok.*

Thanks a ton.